# Simplify Regex on Phone Number in XAML Converter

Tags: c#, regex

C# Regex

Here is a simple converter for WPF using Regex to display a consistent TextBox with a phone number mask:

```
public class MyStringToPhoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return string.Format("(   )    -    ");

    //remove formating...returns a string of digits.
    string phoneNo = value.ToString().Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    // All displayed formating in WPF depends on the control FontSytle. Use a fixed-width,  monospaced, font with no kerning.
    // Examples: Consolas, Courier New, Lucida Console, MS Gothic
    switch (phoneNo.Length)
    {
        case 0:
            return string.Format("(   )    -   ");
        case 1:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{1})", "($1  )    -    ");
        case 2:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{2})", "($1 )    -    ");
        case 3:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})", "($1)    -    ");
        case 4:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{1})", "($1) $2  -    ");
        case 5:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})", "($1) $2 -    ");
        case 6:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})", "($1) $2-    ");
        case 7:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})", "($1) $2-$3   ");
        case 8:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})", "($1) $2-$3  ");
        case 9:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})", "($1) $2-$3 ");
        case 10:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
        case 11:
            return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3-$4");
        default:
            return phoneNo;
    }

}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
```

}

This seems awfully repetitive having to write a different string and regex expression for each string length.

Is there a single one or two regex expressions that can handle the different string lengths with a consistent output format? (I'm not really concerned with 11 digits :) )

TIA

Comment: A bit repetitive but also comprehensive imo. I would prefer this over a short non comprehensive regex, especially when it is combined with output formatting

Comment: As @LennartStoop says, perhaps keeping things simple is better than a complex regex that you will forgot how it works but you can try this if you still insist on it `"^\([0-9]{1,4}\)[-\s\./0-9]*$"` there is no specific range in this example and you can add more complex info to restrict the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an attempt to get rid of multiple Regex templates, and replacement strings. The Regex I came up with is a bit more complicated, and a custom evaluator is required for replacement procedure. Anyways it seems achieves the desired goal.

Some comments:

- `(?<!\d.*)` - makes sure a match starts with the 1st digit
- `((?=\d{11})\d{1})?` - match the 1st group (1 digit) when all 11 digits were provided
- `(\d{1,3})` - allow partially filled groups
- `|^(?!.*\d)` - still match when no digits found

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //remove formating...returns a string of digits.
    string phoneNo = Regex.Replace(value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty, @"[\(\)\- ]", string.Empty);

    return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(?<!\d.*)((?=\d{11})\d{1})?(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,4})?|^(?!.*\d)", m =>
    {
        var gr1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
        var gr2 = m.Groups[2].Value.PadRight(3);
        var gr3 = m.Groups[3].Value.PadRight(3);
        var gr4 = m.Groups[4].Value.PadRight(4);

        return m.Groups[1].Success
            ? $"{gr1}-{gr2}-{gr3}-{gr4}"
            : $"({gr2}) {gr3}-{gr4}";
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow! I'm horrible at Regex, so your explanations provide a great learning tool for me. Your using look arounds and a few other things here that deserve more study - 1+ . (The complexity sure did jump up...so I'm probably inclined to keep the current solution). Thanks!